# Why does `:call f(...)` do nothing while mapping it to a binding works?

Tags: vimscript, functions, plugin-fzf

I'm not really sure how to describe this behavior better than with the example I'm dealing with.

I'm trying to write a custom completion using [fzf-vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) ... and as I'm looking through the documentation, [there is a section that describes how to do it briefly](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/doc/fzf-vim.txt#L303), but since I don't understand it fully, I wanted to play with the API.

So naturally I thought I'd be able to just do

```
:call fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')
```

instead of binding it to a binding and using that binding like they show with

```
inoremap <expr> <c-x><c-k> fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')
```

but the problem is, while the binding does pop up fzf, the `:call fzf#vim#complete(...)` seems to do nothing.

I'm not sure what is causing this behavior, and if there is some other way I should be invoking the function? I don't mind reading stuff up in the documentation and learning about vimscript, but at this point I really don't know where to look anymore

---

As a side note, what I'm actually trying to do is create a fzf wrapper around `:digraph`. I wasn't sure if this would be possible with just the output of `:digraph`, so I found [unicode.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) which even provides a function [FindUnicodeBy](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim/blob/master/autoload/unicode.vim#L31) which seems I should be able to just pass into the `fzf#vim#complete` wrapper, but I can't even figure out how to test the completion function.

Any tips are very welcome, as well as references to stuff to read to be able to work better with vimscript!

Comment: For reading references, the help, vimruntime, and Steve Losh’s « Learn vimscript the hard way » are good starts.

Comment: Jacub, try `:echo fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')`. See `:help :map-expression`.

Answer (score 1):

This touches the implementation details of `fzf#complete`. If you look into the source code of `fzf#vim#complete`, you will see

```
call feedkeys("\<Plug>(-fzf-complete-trigger)")
return ''
```

So when you do `imap <expr> xxxx fzf#vim#complete()`, what returns from the expression is `''`, and the key `\<Plug>(-fzf-complete-trigger)` stored in a buffer and is to be processed later. This key is actually defined by

```
imap <Plug>(-fzf-complete-trigger) <c-o>:call s:_complete_trigger()<cr>
```

There is no `nmap` defined for it. So you won't get anything if you do

```
:call fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')
```

I actually didn't get your purpose to run it in normal mode. But if just want to have this ability, you can do

```
nmap <expr> xxx 'i' . fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')
```

or (this method adds key `i` before `\<Plug>(-fzf-complete-trigger)`

```
:call feedkeys("i") | call fzf#vim#complete('cat /usr/share/dict/words')
```

or to modify fzf source code to expose s:_complete_trigger as a global function and call that function.